# Have you seen my matroid?

Tags: co.combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics, coxeter-groups, matroid-theory

Let $M(n,k)$ be the matroid on the ground set $\{\pm 1,\ldots,\pm n\}$ for which a set is independent if and only if it contains at most $k$ pairs $\pm i$.  Note that the signed permutation group (the Coxeter group of type $B_n$) acts on this matroid. Questions:

1. Does this matroid have a name?
2. Has it been studied before?
3. Is there a nice formula for its characteristic polynomial?

Here are some boring special cases:

- $M(n,n)$ is the Boolean matroid on $2n$ elements.
- $M(n,n-1)$ is the uniform matroid of rank $2n-1$ on $2n$ elements.
- $M(n,0)$ is the direct sum of $n$ copies of the uniform matroid of rank 1 on 2 elements.

The first interesting case is $M(3,1)$, which has rank 4 and characteristic polynomial

$$q^4 - 6q^3 + 15q^2 - 17q + 7$$

I am also interested in truncations of this matroid.  That is, let $M(n,k,d)$ be the matroid on the ground set $\{\pm 1,\ldots,\pm n\}$ for which a set is independent if and only if it contains at most $k$ pairs $\pm i$ and has size at most $d$.  All of the same questions apply!

Remark:  I would like to regard these matroids as type B analogues of uniform matroids.  Uniform matroids are the permutation-invariant matroids on the ground set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, while these are the signed-permutation-invariant matroids on the ground set $\{\pm 1,\ldots,\pm n\}$.

Comment: I hate to be a spoilsport but the title, while cute and attention-grabbing, is a bit too vague for my tastes. As it stands, a reader seeing the title on the main page or a reader that might see the title in the "Related" list on another question page will have no idea of what "your matroid" is like.

Comment: The better known book is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_My_Mother%3F

Comment: @j.c.: Well, a quick search shows 47 questions with titles of the form "Does this ___ have a name?"  Your criticisms would seem to apply to most of those titles as well.  It doesn't seem quite obvious how to produce a more suitable title in such cases.  (For that matter, "Does this matroid have a name?" was already taken.)

Comment: Let us hope the answering post is titled "How I Met Your Matroid".  Gerhard "Sometimes Just Can't Stop Himself" Paseman, 2017.10.30.

Comment: @Will Jagy - I was thinking more of https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18209408-have-you-seen-my-dragon

Comment: just so you know, the title I thought you were going for turned up this: https://www.amazon.com/Have-You-Seen-My-Mother/dp/0976938502  which, well, is not for young readers

Comment: @LouisDeaett Yes, it's not obvious at all, but still I think it's important! Every question with a vague title is a question that could be improved to be that much more helpful to someone searching for answers to the same question. Anyways, I won't belabor the point. I voted the question up by the way.

Comment: This question seems to be a very nice answer to https://mathoverflow.net/q/218523/3032

Comment: More generally: If $A$ and $B$ are two finite sets, if $f : A \to B$ is any map, and if $k$ is any nonnegative integer, then the subsets $S$ of $A$ satisfying $\left|S\right| - \left|f\left(S\right)\right| \leq k$ are the independent sets of a matroid on $A$. Your matroid is obtained if we take $A = \left\{1, \ldots, k\right\} \cup \left\{-1, \ldots, -k\right\}$ and $B = \left\{1, \ldots, k\right\}$ and if $f$ is the absolute-value function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $U$ be the uniform matroid of rank $k$ on $n$. Since $U$ is orientable one can consider the Lawrence oriented matroid $\Lambda(U)$ associated with any orientation of $U$ (the Lawrence construction doesn't care about which orientation you take). Then $M(n,k)$ is precisely the underlying unoriented matroid $\underline{\Lambda(U)}$ of $\Lambda(U)$.

Also, the dual matroid $M^*(n,k)$ is a symplectic matroid, which explains why the group $B_n$ acts on the primal.

Comment: $M(n,k)$ can be constructed by starting with the uniform matroid $U_{k,n}$, and then replacing each element with a series pair. Alternatively, $M^{*}(n,k)$ is constructed by starting with the uniform matroid $U_{n-k,n}$ and adding an element in parallel to each point of the uniform matroid. I'm not aware of any name for these classes in the matroid literature.

Answer (score 19):

One can use Whitney's theorem to show that the characteristic polynomial is
  $$ \sum_{i=0}^k{n\choose i}q^{k-i}(q-2)^{n-i} +
    \sum_{i=k+1}^n{n\choose i}(q-2)^{n-i}. $$
I doubt that this can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks, this is a pretty reasonable formula!  Certainly well suited to putting into a generating function.